# Select a table where table name is stored in another table

Tags: sql, ms-access, dynamic-tables

I have Access dba with a staging table where I store all table names.
Table name: SourceTable
tbl name field: SourceID
key field: ReferenceID

I would like to create SELECT query where "FROM table" is actually a dynamic table name based on SQL query. Something similar to this:

```
Select * from 'select SourceID from SourceTable where ReferenceID=1';
```

Comment: I'm not shore but your statement need to look like this:
Select SourceID from SourceTable where ReferenceID=?;

Comment: "Select SourceID from SourceTable where ReferenceID" this query selects a certain Table Name then using this name I need to select all the locums from it.

Comment: Table name and field names cannot be dynamic in a query object.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do something with VBA to accomplish this.

- Put a combobox that gets its items from your SourceTable on a form
- Add a textfield on the form with your reference ID
- Add a button on the form with the following On_Click code

Select the table name, enter your Reference ID, and click the button

```
    Private Sub cmdQuery_Click()
        Dim qdf As QueryDef 'Query definition containter'
        Dim mySQL As String 'SQL Statement container'
        Dim t As String     'table name containter'
        Dim rid As String   'ReferenceID container'

        'getting values for your table and ReferenceID'
        t = cboTableNames.Value
        rid = txtRID.Value

       'building SQL string'
       mySQL = "Select * from " & t & " WHERE ReferenceID=" & rid & ";"

       'Delete the query if it already exists'
       DoCmd.DeleteObject acQuery, "NewQuery"

       'building query' 
       Set qdf = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("NewQuery", mySQL)

       'running query'
       DoCmd.OpenQuery qdf.Name

       'closing query'
       qdf.Close

       'clearing memory'
       Set qdf = Nothing
    End Sub
```